# Can you "hg rebase --svn" from TortoiseHg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I'm using hgsubversion + mercurial against an SVN repo.
I notice that the rebase from TortoiseHg seems to corrupt my repository 
(I can no longer push to Subversion)

Can I mimic `hg rebase --svn` from the TortoiseHg UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  When you choose Modify History > Rebase from the right click menu, you should be presented with the following dialog box:

[image: Rebase dialog showing the SVN option]

The bottom option is labelled "Rebase unpublished onto Subversion head (override source, destination)"

Tick that box and press the Rebase button and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't using the latest version of THG.